# Why didn't java completely adhere to the monitor concept

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

From my understanding of the monitor concept, in the terminology of Java, a monitor has these properties:

> A monitor is a class with only private fields.
>
> Each object of that class has an associated lock.
>
> All methods are locked by that lock .
>
> The lock can have any number of associated conditions.

But java objects differs from the monitor concept,

> Fields are not required to be private.
>
> Methods are not required to be `synchronized`.
>
> And when dealing with `synchronized` keyword the lock can have one associated condition.

Why doesn't java `synchronized` give access to multiple associated conditions? And why doesn't java completely adhere to the rules of the monitor concept.

Comment: I don’t think your understanding is correct.  A monitor can be any object;  its fields are irrelevant.  Monitors do not inherently lock any methods.  Monitors do not have any conditions associated with them (but [explicit Lock objects can](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#newCondition%28%29)).  And there is no reason to make methods or blocks synchronized if thread safety is not needed.  Synchronization has a cost in terms of performance.

Comment: What is your source for the first four claims? (A monitor is a class with only private fields, ...)

Comment: @ThomasKläger I read the book core java by Cay S Horstmann

Comment: @VGR thanks a lot for the information!